# Disable IRQ on STM32

Tags: c, arm, stm32, interrupt, cortex-m

Is there any way to disable all irq from Cortex M3 MCU except one ?

My issue is that I have a system running several kinds of irq with various priority levels and I want to disable all irq except one in a particular state.

I know I can disable all irq by using "__disable_irq()" instruction but I can't enable one irq after calling this instruction if I didn't call "__enable_irq()" before.

Thanks for your help,

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use the `BASEPRI` register to disable all interrupts below the specified priority level.**

This is a core register, described in the [Cortex-M3 Programming Manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/cd00228163.pdf).

[image]

CMSIS provides the `__get_BASEPRI()` and `__set_BASEPRI()` functions to manipulate its value.

Note that bits 7-4 are used, the priority value must be shifted left by 4. To disable all interrupts with priority 1 or lower, use

```
__set_BASEPRI(1 << 4);
```

and to enable all, set it to 0

```
__set_BASEPRI(0);
```

You should of course set interrupt priorities accordingly, ensuring that no other interrupt has priority 0.

Comment: FYI: You do not shift by 4 when the cpu is a CM4.

Comment: @FelipeLavratti ST implements only bits 7-4, i.e. 16 priority levels on its Cortex-M4 MCUs (F3, F4, L3). Other manufacturers might do it differently.

Comment: My friend, not really. This is ARM implementation, not manufacturer. And CM4 spec says that the bits are 0-7 instead 4-7 on CM4. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDBIBGJ.html

Comment: The question is about STM32, and the ST manual says only bits 7-4 are implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Other than by disabling all the enabled interrupts you don't want, no.

`__disable_irq()` is implemented as `CPSID I`, which turns off all exceptions which can have a priority set (those configured in the NVIC), it achieves this by changing the `PRIMASK` register (setting bit 0) within the CPU. There is no way to tell this to only enable a specific interrupt.